# What's the indication of the scissor symbol in Flutter paint debug mode?

Tags: debugging, flutter, mobile-application

When I toggle the Paint Debug mode in a Flutter mobile app, there's a scissor appears at the left top of the AppBar (the picture). What's its indication? It's not that important question, but I always get curious when I see it.

[image]

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: @FernandoSantos no I didn't.

Comment: Well, in my case, it was the representation of a ClipRRect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Flutter inspector's documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/inspector#clipping), it is written that this is to represent a clipping:

> Clipping, for example when using the [ClipRect widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipRect-class.html), are shown with a dashed pink line with a scissors icon.